# Matrices: Anyone have a real-life problem that uses matrices / linear systems of equations?

Tags: matrices

Looking for something beyond a contrived textbook problem concerning jelly beans. Not just matrix manipulation for it's own sake.

I know matrix math is used in real life applications (finance, science, manufacturing, optimizing, etc) ... to solve linear systems of equations. Has anyone ever used this Math to solve a real problem at work, etc? come across a real example? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Applications of systems of linear equations](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44548/applications-of-systems-of-linear-equations)

Comment: No. All matrix problems are contrived. They are there as a test and a rite of passage. In centuries past, a young man could return from a solo hunt, or prove himself in battle. Now we have matrices.

Comment: I suggest reading the book *Thirty-three Miniatures: Mathematical and Algorithmic Applications of Linear Algebra* by Jiří Matoušek: http://www.ams.org/bookstore?fn=20&arg1=stmlseries&ikey=STML-53  Real life is overrated anyway.

Comment: Try reading the Wikipedia article onPage

Comment: Try reading the Wikipedia article on PageRank, in particular the sentence "The PageRank values are the entries of the dominant eigenvector of the modified adjcency matrix"

Comment: The PageRank example was useful for my discussion.  Any others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say that you want to start a public works company, but don't know how high/low to make your bids to the city for projects. (Note: a "bid" lists the type and number of goods/services and the *total cost*, not the price per good)

If you can find sufficiently many **past bids** (with sufficiently many of the goods/services that you would offer) from a single competitor, you can solve a matrix equation to determine what this competitor charges for their goods/services.

*(Here I make some assumptions about linearity)*

Comment: Anyone have a link to a specific example online somewhere?

Comment: Can you post a simple example of this with actual numbers?

Comment: I'll have to Work something up and edit when I'm not on a touchscreen. Stay tuned :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example from structural engineering:

You have a multiple degree-of-freedom system, and each system can be modeled as a spring-mass-damper system with a forcing term. These degrees of freedom are coupled.

If you write out the equations, you realize that the same terms appear in every equation. Then, voila! You have a matrix differential equation.

Then again, maybe this is contrived, since my work involves modeling these types of systems!

Answer (score 0):

Look up a linear programming/optimization book.  I seem to recall an example where Delta airlines used LP (based on matrix arguments) to significantly reduce costs.

Answer (score 0):

I use matrices in various programming situations. In the short and simple, arrays, structures, and objects are all matrix-like implementations. They sure make handling multi-variable systems easier.

Will Jagy might leave his cave from time to time.

Comment: Will's comment was obviously tongue-in-cheek.